# Jenkins with docker-compose got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I want to setup some dockerized tool on my vps. That includes jenkins and a proxy. Everything is building fine but when using the docker agent in jenkins I run into this error :

```
+ docker build -t 286802dd81862d714cfc6a90c84d30200546eaa9 -f Dockerfile .

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=srtihghhshf8z9c2lkdnvr8dm&shmsize=0&t=286802dd81862d714cfc6a90c84d30200546eaa9&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

script returned exit code 1
```

here is what my docker-compose looks like :

```
services:

  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always

  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    ...

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ...

  jenkins:
    image: jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=jenkins.mydomain.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - ./jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro
      - ./jenkins-home:/home
    restart: always

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Am I missing something in my compose file ?

So far I have tried adding the jenkins user to the docker and root group on the running docker instance but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to fix this. I simply specified the root user in the docker-compose.yml like this :

```
  jenkins:
    image: jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
    user: root
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=jenkins.mydomain.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - ./jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro
      - ./jenkins-home:/home
    restart: always
```